# c++ pass string as refrence in header and cpp

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, pass-by-reference

how to pass string as reference in constructor in header and cpp
using cin to get the line in a text file. 
by execute this command prompt: program < test.txt

text.txt

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

main.cpp

```
include "read.h"
include <iostream>
include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

string output;

Read read(line);

while (getline(cin, line)) {
    Read.run();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Read.cpp

```
include "Read.h"
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Read::Read(string& input) : currentLine(input) {   
}

void Read::run() {
    cout << "currentLine:" << currentLine << "\r\n";        
}
```

Read.h

```
class Read{
public:
    std::string currentLine;

    Parser(std::string& s);

    void advance();
}
```

When I execute this program in cmd:
program < test.txt
the currentLine does not have value

Comment: in Read read(line);  what is line?

Comment: Parser(std::string& s); should be Read(std::string& s); ?

Comment: void advance(); should be  void run();?  :D

Comment: c has neither references nor classes nor iostreams! Dont spam unrelated tags

Answer (score 0):

```
string output;

Read read(line);

while (getline(cin, line)) {
    Read.run();
    ...
    ...
}
```

You set `read.currentLine` to `input` (in the constructor) but `currentLine` isn't a reference, so it will just be copied, resulting in an empty string. Make `currentLine` a reference too. Beware of dangling references though.